# Using Rails Data for a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I access the `@location.coordinates` data and use it in the `GetMarineWeather()` function for the query?

I want to be able to use the rails data and load the query coordinates.

How can I access the coordinates and fill the function when the page is loaded initially?

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p><strong>Name:</strong><%= @location.name %></p>

<p><strong>Sub region:</strong><%= @location.sub_region %></p>

<p><strong>Region:</strong><%= @location.region %></p>

<p><strong>Coordinates:</strong><%= @location.coordinates %></p>

<div id="resultContainer"></div>


<!-- *********************************************************************** -->


<script type="text/javascript">

  var resultContainer = $('#resultContainer');
  var output = '';


  $(document).ready(function () {
    GetMarineWeather();
  });


  function GetMarineWeather(e) {
    var marineWeatherInput = {
        query: '26.16,-80.10',
        format: 'JSON',
        fx: '',
        callback: 'MarineWeatherCallback'
    };
    JSONP_MarineWeather(marineWeatherInput);
    e.preventDefault();
  }


  function MarineWeatherCallback(marineWeather) {

      output = "<br/> Date: " + marineWeather.data.weather[0].date;
      output += "<br/> Min Temp (f): " + marineWeather.data.weather[0].mintempF;
      output += "<br/> Max Temp (f): " + marineWeather.data.weather[0].maxtempF;
      output += "<br/> Cloud Cover: " + marineWeather.data.weather[0].hourly[0].cloudcover;

      resultContainer.empty();
      resultContainer.html(output);

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to set a `data-` attributes on a HTML tag to share server side information with JavaScript.

```
<div id="coordinates" data-coordinates="<%= @location.coordinates %>"></div>
```

After that you simply read it with JS:

```
$('#coordinates').data('coordinates')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the information when the page is loaded you can always just print it directly in your javascript.

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetMarineWeather('<%= @location.coordinates %>');
});
```

If the information needs to be reloaded I would probably go for an XMLRequest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend for passing Rails vars from a view to a JavaScript function:

```
<%= javascript_tag "GetMarineWeather(#{@location.coordinates.to_json});" %>
```

You may want to split the coordinates to lat + long before you apply .to_json

```
<%= javascript_tag "GetMarineWeather((#{@latitude.to_json}, #{@longitude.to_json}));" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides there is also cool gem called 'gon' 
https://github.com/gazay/gon